Proof that the Completion of a Semi-Metric Space is Complete
I have just finished a proof that the completion of a semi-metric space is complete, but it seems like it could be cleaner, and I would appreciate any pointers or corrections.
Edit: A semi-metric space is a set $X$ with a function $\rho:X\times X\to [0,\infty)$ such that for all $x,y,z\in X$: (i) $\rho(x,y) = \rho(y,x)$; (ii) $\rho(x,z)\leq \rho(x,y)+\rho(y,z)$, and (iii) $\rho(x,x) = 0$.
Here is my proof:
Let $(X,\rho)$ be a semi-metric space, let $(X^{\sharp},\rho^{\sharp})$ be the semi-metric space consisting of Cauchy sequences in $X$ with $\rho^{\sharp}(\left\{x_{n}\right\},\left\{y_{n}\right\}) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\rho(x_{n},y_{n})$, and write $\left\{x_{n}\right\}\equiv\left\{y_{n}\right\}$ if $\rho^{\sharp}(\left\{x_{n}\right\},\left\{y_{n}\right\}) = 0$. Finally, let $\widetilde{X} = X^{\sharp}/\equiv$ and consider the metric $\tilde{\rho}(\left[\left\{x_{n}\right\}\right],\left[\left\{y_{n}\right\}\right])
= \rho^{\sharp}(\left\{x_{n}\right\},\left\{y_{n}\right\})$. I have shown that $(\widetilde{X},\tilde{\rho})$ is a metric space.
So let $\left\{\alpha_{n}\right\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a Cauchy sequence of members of $\widetilde{X}$ and let $\left\{a_{i}^{n}\right\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ be a representative for $\alpha_{n}$. We need to find $\gamma\in \widetilde{X}$ such that $\alpha_{n}\to \gamma$. Since $\left\{\alpha_{n}\right\}$ is Cauchy, for all $\varepsilon>0$ there exists an $N$ such that for $n,m>N$, $\tilde{\rho}(\alpha_{n},\alpha_{m}) < \varepsilon$. Therefore, for $n,m>N$, we have
\begin{equation*} \tilde{\rho}(\alpha_{n},\alpha_{m})  = \rho^{\sharp}\left(\left\{a_{i}^{n}\right\},\left\{a_{i}^{m}\right\}\right)
= \lim_{i\to \infty}{\rho(a_{i}^{n},a_{i}^{m})} < \varepsilon. \end{equation*}
Now consider a representative for $\alpha_{k}$, $\left\{a_{i}^{k}\right\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$. Since the representative is Cauchy, for all $\varepsilon>0$ we can find $N_{k}$ such that for all $p,q>N_{k}$, $\rho(a_{p}^{k},a_{q}^{k})<\varepsilon$. So let $j>N_{k}$ and write $y_{k} = a_{j}^{k}$. Then
\begin{equation*} \rho(y_{k},a_{i}^{k}) < \varepsilon \end{equation*}
for all $i>N_{k}$. For each $k$, consider the constant sequence $\left\{y_{k},y_{k},\ldots\right\}$. This is a convergent sequence (to $y_{k}$) in $X$ and so it is Cauchy, whereby it is a member of $X^{\sharp}$. Now put $\gamma_{k} = \left[\left\{y_{k}\right\}\right]$. We see that
\begin{equation*} \tilde{\rho}(\alpha_{k},\gamma_{k}) = \rho^{\sharp}\left(\left\{a_{i}^{k}\right\}_{i=1}^{\infty},\left\{y_{k}\right\}\right)
= \lim_{k\to\infty}\rho(a_{i}^{k},y_{k}) < \varepsilon. \end{equation*}
Now consider
\begin{equation*} \left\{y_{i}\right\}_{i=1}^{\infty}\hspace{1pc}\mbox{ with }\hspace{1pc}\gamma = \left[\left\{y_{i}\right\}_{i=1}^{\infty}\right].  \end{equation*}
To see that this is Cauchy, note that for all $\varepsilon>0$ we can find $N$ so that
\begin{equation*} \rho(y_{n},y_{m})\leq \rho(y_{m},a_{i}^{m}) + \rho(a_{i}^{m},a_{i}^{n}) + \rho(a_{i}^{n},y_{n}) < \varepsilon \end{equation*}
as long as $m,n>N$. Therefore, $\left\{y_{i}\right\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ is Cauchy, and is a member of $X^{\sharp}$. Also, we have that $\tilde{\rho}(\gamma_{k},\gamma)\to 0$. To see this, consider the sequence
\begin{equation*} d_{k} = \tilde{\rho}(\gamma,\gamma_{k}) = \rho^{\sharp}\left(\left\{y_{k},y_{k},\ldots\right\},\left\{y_{1},y_{2},\ldots\right\}\right)
= \lim_{n\to\infty}\rho(y_{k},y_{n}) < \varepsilon \end{equation*}
for any $\varepsilon$, where $k,n>N$ are sufficiently large. Then since $d_{k}$ is a Cauchy sequence of real numbers, it converges, and we see that it does so to zero. Therefore, we have that $\gamma_{k}\to \gamma$. Finally, for any $\varepsilon$ there exists an $N$ such that $k>N$ implies
\begin{equation*} \tilde{\rho}(\alpha_{k},\gamma) \leq \tilde{\rho}(\alpha_{k},\gamma_{k}) + \tilde{\rho}(\gamma_{k},\gamma) < \varepsilon  \end{equation*}
since $\tilde{\rho}(\alpha_{k},\gamma_{k})$ and $\tilde{\rho}(\gamma_{k},\gamma)$ can be made arbitrarily small. Therefore $\alpha_{k}\to \gamma$, so $\left\{\alpha_{n}\right\}$ is convergent.

You may want to start with a definition of a semi-metric space.  This is not as well-known as a metric space.

@MikhailKatz Thank you for your suggestion---I added that definition

So if the distance function vanishes identically, that would give an example of a semi-metric space?  It seems as though it may not be easy to construct a completion under the circumstances.

If it vanishes identically, I think it reduces $\widetilde{X}$ to just one point, since every member of $X$ is by definition Cauchy and $\rho^{\sharp}(\left{x_{n}\right},\left{y_{n}\right}) = 0$ for all members of $X^{\sharp}$. Each sequence in $X^{\sharp}$ is equivalent to every other sequence in $X^{\sharp}$.

I only need advice showing that the metric space $(\widetilde{X},\tilde{\rho})$ is complete.

Show that for each Cauchy sequence in $X$, there is an equivalent sequence ${x_n}$ such that for each $\epsilon > 0,  n,m >\frac 1\epsilon \implies \rho(x_n,x_m) < \epsilon$ (a subsequence of the known sequence is adequate). Then when you have your Cauchy sequence ${\alpha_n}_n$ in $\widetilde X$, choose your representative sequences for each $\alpha_n$ to satisfy this condition. That uniformity of convergence rates frees you from a lot of the hassles of your approach.
